# Improve useability of local network share

Tags: document-management, sharing

I work in academics and our department has a local server with a network share that is accessible for everyone within our local network. It is used to store various types of data (text, pictures, binary) that "might be relevant to everyone working here".

Now, as one can imagine, over the years this became a pretty convoluted folder structure of which nobody knows for sure what is to be found there and where.

Of course bringing some order to this and throwing out stuff that isn't needed anymore is one thing, but I was also wondering if there is software out there that allows for a better overview by creating some sort of graphical interface to show all the contents and the structure of the network share's file system and would even allow to enter some metadata.

However, we would need this to be mostly self-populating/automatic. Basically what I would like is an automatic CMS/DMS that visualizes a network share's file system structure to aid people in extracting relevant information (or at least be sure that they didn't miss anything). Advanced search features would also be a plus.

Does anyone know of a software/tool/framework that goes in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything automated, but at many companies I've worked at we've used [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) as an internal wiki of sorts to organize data and documentation.  Confluence has an import feature, where a word document and/or image/video can be imported into a page.  I believe it can even be organized by workspace/department so for example IT can have a separate searchable space than your other academic department(s).